# UITableView indexing or sorting image array , description array according to name array

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I'm using UITableView. I'm displaying Name , small description and thumb url image. I'm able to show indexing for the class on the basis of username (Name array) and its working fine.

But my another arrays (description array) and thumb URL image (Image array) are not displaying data correctly . They are repeating themselves for new sections.

What i want : If i sorted an array from A to Z and showing indexing. All other array should be sorted same way.

right now image array and description array are repeating for new section.

Please help.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefaultreuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    NSArray *listData =[self.tableContents objectForKey:

                        [self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]];

    UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    lbl1.frame =   NSArray *listData =[self.tableContents objectForKey:

                        [self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]];

    UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    lbl1.frame = CGRectMake(95, 02, 225, 25);
    lbl1.text = listData[indexPath.row];CGRectMake(95, 02, 225, 25);
    lbl1.text = listData[indexPath.row];


    UILabel *lbl2 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    lbl2.frame = CGRectMake(95, 25, 230, 15);
    lbl2.text = date_array[indexPath.row];   //this one is not working

     return cell;
      }
```

Comment: Any code for cellForRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: NSArray *listData =[self.tableContents objectForKey:
                        [self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]];
    
    UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    lbl1.frame =   NSArray *listData =[self.tableContents objectForKey:
                        [self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]];
    
    UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    lbl1.frame = CGRectMake(95, 02, 225, 25);
    lbl1.text = listData[indexPath.row];CGRectMake(95, 02, 225, 25);
    lbl1.text = listData[indexPath.row];

This is displaying correct name in row

Comment: R u for real??? Edit your question :/

Comment: ok done , please check now

Comment: U r not fetch the image in the code above. Why u expect that the image  will change? in which code line?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue once. The repetition is caused by the reusing of UITableViewCell.

You can clear the values of the UILabel and UIImageView as the first line of the above function and then try to run the code.